# Car Program using Getters and Setters Issues

Tags: java

For this Program the instance variables make and model need to be a string, price needs to be a double which I already have, but not sure what to do with year that needs to be of type int and greater then 1900. I then need to make a constructor with argument which I have done as well but the toString needs to return the string representation of a Car object with the setters and getters methods. So I am having an issue trying to come up with something for the setters and if I am doing this section right.

```
public class Car {

private String make;
private String model;
private double price;
private int year;

public Car(String make, String model, double price, int year) {

    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
    this.year = year;

}

private String getMake() {
    return make;
}

private void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

private String getModel() {
    return model;
}

private void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

private double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

private void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

private int getYear() {
    return year;
}

private void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String toString() {

    return "Make of Car: " + getMake() + "\n Model of Car: " + getModel()
            + "\n Price of Car: " + getPrice() + "\n Year of Car: " + getYear();

}

}
```

This section is the CarTest driver and I am not sure if I did this properly. I have to have a Main method that Instantiates a Car object car1 by invoking the argument constructor and display to the console the string representation of the object car1 using the method toString. Also asking the user to enter values for each instance variable and use the setter type methods to assign the entered values to the corresponding instance variables of the object car1 then I need to display the string representation of the object car1 by invoking the toString method. Am I doing this part right?

```
public class CarTest {

static Car car1;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Make?");
    String make = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Model?");
    String model = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Price?");
    double price = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Year?");
    int year  = scan.nextInt();

    car1 = new Car(make,model,price,year);

    System.out.print(car1.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: If your main program is going to use the setter methods, the setter methods have to be `public`, not `private`.  Other than that, it looks like you're doing fine, although I could have missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do the checking when taking the user input, or the constructor (or both)

```
int year = 0;
while (year < 1900) {
    System.out.println("Year? ");
    year = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I can understand pitting this in the input but how in the constructor? would it be the same because I think you would have to write it differently

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good to me. Maybe you don't need to have the getters if you have the toString method, which returns all the attributes of the car. Juste have the variables and the to string in the return and remove the getters

Good work!

Comment: but for the year I have to make it greater then 1900 when they enter the "year" of the car

Comment: do I need to change that in the setter?

Comment: Why would it matter if the year is greater than 1900?

Comment: Ok now I got it, check zymus answer about that :)